# Draggable fixed element centered in body causing it to snap to left in IE and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have been having a problem centering a fixed div in IE and Chrome when using the JQuery draggable function with a 'containment'. It seems whenever I try to drag the element, it snaps to the left of the containing element until I let go of it and then start dragging again.

Here's an example:

**CodePen**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqZjbX

**HTML**

```
<div class="draggable">
</div>
```

**.CSS**

```
.draggable {
  background: salmon;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: move;
}

body {
  height: 500px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: 'body'
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `.draggable()` is not intended to be used with two properties of the same axis(`left` and `right` in your case). You have to use some other technique to center the element.

Please see example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: 'body'
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  background: salmon;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: move;

  /* Initial position */
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggable">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm a dummy. Can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that the left margin affects the draggable, though (it can be moved outside of the containment).. Any ideas to fix that?